# How to convert xlsx to pdf on one page

Tags: soffice

I have a 13 column xlsx and I want convert to pdf.
I use this code: "soffice" ,"--headless","--convert-to", "pdf" , filepath ,"--outdir",outpath.
I can convert to pdf but the columns too many so they have been showed on four pages.
I need they show on one page.
And it show on straight , I need it show on horizontal.
Thanks

Comment: But how to set soffice a3 landscape

Comment: Which parameter should I set?

Answer (score 0):

XLSX printout settings  (PDF export) are part of the file contents so here is the same file saved with different  settings but same export command. (convert-to implies headless, so not generally needed. The author decides a cell content and shape and also sets how many rows and columns will fit in a standard page such as A4 portrait or A4 Landscape etc. Thus only a macro can change **print layout area**. The best that may be possible externally is to scale it up or down on to bigger or smaller paper.

```
soffice --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export "DataTables example Default.xlsx"
soffice --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export "DataTables example A3.xlsx"
```

You need to change layout for printing and export in the preview screen if you want 13 columns you set area from A:1 to M:Y where Y is your desired number of lines (whatever their variable height may be.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only preview screen can change?

Comment: Can I add parameters in " soffice -- convert -to pdf:cal_pdf_Export "a3.xlsx" "?

Comment: is there a way to convert only the first sheet to pdf. i have multiple sheets.in that i need to convert only the first one

Answer (score 0):

From https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/libreoffice-xls-to-pdf-conversion-breaks-single-page-content-into-multiple-pages-on-ubuntu-18-04/49104/2

Linux:

```
soffice --convert-to 'pdf:calc_pdf_Export:{"SinglePageSheets":{"type":"boolean","value":"true"}}' test.ods
```

Windows:

```
soffice --convert-to "pdf:calc_pdf_Export:{\"SinglePageSheets\":{\"type\":\"boolean\",\"value\":\"true\"}}" test.ods
```